# Maximum Ambient temperature

Tags: voltage, current, temperature, thermal

In this [IC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/00001726B.pdf), on page 35, the maximum operating temperature is given as 70degC or 85degC.

Is the datasheet maximum temperature value of 85C applicable to the surrounding medium? I ask because air will not be in contact with this component; it will be another material.

Comment: I would read it as: the chip is designed to be used in still air up to this temperature. of course the chip doesn't know it's not in air but maybe design it to remove heat equivalent to this, or use it at lower temperatures. There might be more detailed thermal information elsewhere in the datasheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data sheet is specifying the maximum ambient temperature in still air. Usually they are assuming some sort of mounting configuration, that had a specific thermal resistance from the die to the ambient. A quick scan of the specification sheet gave me no more information about the thermal resistances of the part. If you are serious about some sort of mounting scheme that is much different from standard you will have to contact the manufacturer for guidance. Still air usually means no fan in an enclosure. It's really not completely still though as there is still convection inside the enclosure.

If you are considering potting the board that the part will be on then consider the heat conductive properties of the potting compound. Typically parts on circuit boards are cooled first by conduction into the board and then by convection, as the warm regions of the board set up air flow. If you are are potting the part you will only have conduction. If the thermal resistance is equivalent or better than typical conduction plus convection, then you might be able to run the part at a higher Ta. You still need to know the thermal resistance of the die to the package, though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The main criteria is that max junction temperature should not be violated. If your surrounding medium conducts heat better than air then, allowed ambient could even be higher. In any case, better to consult the IC manufacturer.